# how to combine 2 independent boost::bind() into one boost::function?

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I have 2 functions `f()` and `g()`. I want to call them in order every time. Can I get a `boost::function` to do this?
E.g. something like:

```
boost::function functor = boost::bind( boost::bind(f), boost::bind(g) );
```

Extend this further, say it takes arguments, then what I need is a chain of responsibility. Each node does something with arguments, then followed by next node of chain.
How do I do that?

---

**Update** Thanks for Seth Carnegie's comments.
I think what I really want is how to construct a chain of responsibility into a single `boost::function`, each node of chain can be constructed by using `boost::bind()`.

Comment: `bind` is for binding arguments to functions, not for binding functions together in a chain

Comment: Do you mean `f( g( x ) )`, or `f( x ); g( x )`?

Comment: `boost::bind` isn't really the right tool.  Maybe `boost.signals` or `boost.signals2`?

Comment: What you describe matches the semantics of Twisted's Deferred object. There are c++ implementations of it that might be worth looking at: http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2008-October/018548.html

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I meant f(x); g(x); that's why I added independent.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: thanks. Then probably I should change my question to how to make a chain of responsibility.

Comment: Now that what you want is clear, I think you'll have to write a class to do this yourself, unless you want to (and can) make use of lambdas like `boost::function functor = [=]() { f(); g(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [boost::signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/signals.html%20boost%3a%3asignal) ?

With boost::signal you can connect multiple function calls into one.

```
#include <boost/signal.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

void f() 
{ 
  std::cout << " Hello" << std::flush; 
} 

void g() 
{ 
  std::cout << " World" << std::endl; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  boost::signal<void ()> s; 
  s.connect(f); 
  s.connect(g); 
  s(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not quite what I wanted. not simple enough

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?

```
#include <functional>

template <typename FirstFunctor, typename SecondFunctor>
void chainFunctionImpl(FirstFunctor first, SecondFunctor second)
{
   first();
   second();
}

template <typename FirstFunctor, typename SecondFunctor>
std::function<void(void)> chainFunction(FirstFunctor first, SecondFunctor second)
{
   return std::bind(chainFunctionImpl<FirstFunctor,SecondFunctor>,first,second);
}
```

Use should be relatively simple, just binding the functions in sequence, then calling the result. Theoretically any length of functions could be chained up.

Note that is theoretically possible to do this with passing an argument down the chain as well, but that level of template foo is way beyond me. http://ideone.com/Xvp5U is where I gave up.

Comment: For the template *foo*, my advice would be to avoid function templates end go for class templates that implement a static function. If your compiler supports variable templates the implementation is actually quite simple.

Comment: thanks, but this is not quite what I wanted. not simple enough

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite easy solution using boost::lambda with its comma operator. In my case I am using it for a modificator function which is defined as (B is an arbitrary class for e.g. and A is a class which should be altered but resides in B and should not go outside)

```
void B::modify( boost::function<void(A&)> func );
```

My intention is to pass only the modificator to the modify function which makes it more easy to gain control when it is modified (for e.g. for emitting signals).

Sometimes I want to apply 2 modifier:

```
void A::setInvalid();
void A::setX( int x );
```

Calling in 2 steps which is not the way (just as reference to show how we want to use the modify method):

```
instanceA->modify( 
    boost::bind( &A::setInvalid, _1 );
instanceA->modify( 
    boost::bind( &A::setX, _1, 4 );
```

Using boost::lambda this can be joined to a single function call and therefore only one function is created:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;
instanceA->modify(
    ( bind(&A::setInvalid, boost::lambda::_1)
    , bind(&A::setX, boost::lambda::_1, 4) ) );
```

Related to your question this would look then:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
boost::function<void()> func = ( bind(f), bind(g) )
```